# как правильно повернуть изображение?

Tags: perl, gd

Целиком код приводить не буду, тк он все равно черновой, остановлюсь на основных моментах. Имеем такие данные:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000111000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000111100000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000001011100000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000011001110000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000011001110000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000010000111000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000110000111000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000100000011100000000000000000000
00000000000000000001111111111100000000000000000000
00000000000000000001000000011100000000000000000000
00000000000000000011000000001110000000000000000000
00000000000000000011000000001110000000000000000000
00000000000000000110000000000111000000000000000000
00000000000000001110000000001111100000000000000000
00000000000000011111100000011111110000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

И основная часть кода:

```
my $radians = 20 * (pi / 180);
......
for my $w(0..$width -1){
  for my $h(0..$height -1){
    my $nx = int(cos($radians) * ($h - 25) - sin($radians) * ($w - 25) + 25);
    my $ny = int(sin($radians) * ($h - 25) + cos($radians) * ($w - 25) + 25);
```

изображение 50 * 50 pix, немного обрезал для вставки в пост
где "25" - центр - нулевая точка отчета в системе координат декарта = $width / 2 & $height / 2
поворачиваем данные/картинку на 20 гр. по часовой и вот что получаем:

[image: йййййй]

Разобрался откуда эти черные пиксели беруться:
"The coordinate system starts at the upper left at (0,0) and gets larger as you go down and to the right. You can use a real color, or one of the special colors gdBrushed, gdStyled and gdStyledBrushed can be specified."
 Если попытаться применить пиксель с отрицательным значением координат, или же число пикселей будет меньше указанных при создании картинки - будет заменять черным.

Comment: а в чём проблема заключается?

Comment: да, забыл добавить, появляются черные точки, при повороте в более 20 град идут сильные искажения и провалы - теряются черные пиксели, и по краям убрать черную рамку, все кроме "A" белым, вращение по центру

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы избавиться от пропусков, нужно действовать так - не для каждой точки исходного изображения находить соответствующую повернутую, а наоборот - каждой точке конечного изображения находить соотв. точку исходного. В формулах изменится знак угла.

```
for my $w(0..$width -1){
  for my $h(0..$height -1){
     my $nx = int(cos($radians) * ($h - 25) + sin($radians) * ($w - 25) + 25);
     my $ny = int( - sin($radians) * ($h - 25) + cos($radians) * ($w - 25) + 25);
   if ($nx < 0) or ($nx >=$width) or ($ny < 0) or ($ny >=$height)
       красить ($w, $h)  белым
   else 
       красить ($w, $h)  в цвет ($nx, $ny)
```

Если точка выходит за пределы исходной картинки (получаются отрицательные или слишком большие координаты) -  закрашивать белым.

Округление все равно приведёт к искажениям, но они будут не настолько бросающиеся в глаза.

Delphi код генерирует картинку ниже:

```
  tmp := TStringList.Create;
  SetLength(a, 50, 50);
  lst.LoadFromFile('e:\letter.txt');
  for i := 0 to lst.Count - 1 do
    for j := 1 to Length(lst[i]) do
      a[i, j - 1] := StrToInt(lst[i][j]);
  an := DegToRad(20);
  for Y := 0 to 49 do
    for X := 0 to 49 do begin
      ox := Floor(25 + (X - 25) * Cos(an) + (Y - 25) * Sin(an));
      oy := Floor(25 - (X - 25) * Sin(an) + (Y - 25) * Cos(an));
      if (ox < 0) or (oy < 0) or (ox >= 50) or (oy >= 50) then
        Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite
      else if a[oy, ox] = 0 then
        Canvas.Brush.Color := clGray
      else
        Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
      Canvas.FillRect(Rect(X * 10, Y * 10, X * 10 + 10, Y * 10 + 10));
    end;
end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а более развернутый ответ можно получить? то есть, как я понял, не "cos($radians)" а подругому

Comment: Нет, синус будет с другим знаком. Остальная часть формулы при вращении вокруг центра останется такой же

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/a0ZXZ6d.png

Comment: по идее, отрицательных значений быть не должно, разная система координат, возможно, нужна какая-то трансформация?

Comment: Если мы поворачиваем в одном и том же прямоугольнике относительно центра, уголки будут вылезать за рамку. У меня во второй формуле минус не там стоял, сейчас поправил

Comment: ничего не поменялось, все так-же как и на картинке, что-то мне кажется что - без предварительной конвертации из текстового формата в формат декарта и обратного преобразования - не получится, другие входные данные, либо изначально, при чтении бинарного изображения сразу добавлять в соотв. формат

Comment: на -+ 90 180 270 - получаются почти чистые и без искажений - но для этого нет смысла использовать син.кос - достаточно сделать перестановку с определенным шагом

Comment: А что вы хотите получить при повороте "изображения " такого низкого разрешения? Потери неизбежны. На больших картинках искажения на  один пиксел просто невелики относительно общего размера, но никуда не исчезают.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85879/discussion-between-usr13-and-mbo).